# Размеры, проценты

Tags: css, padding

Есть основной div с контентом. В нем есть div с картинкой (кнопочка play). Диву с картинкой задаю padding-top 40%, а он оказывается почти в самом низу блока. В чем ошибка и как правильно считать?

[image]

Comment: 40% от какой величины? ну и стоит разметку и остальные стили добавить

Comment: <div class="watch-story-content">
   <div class="watch-story-button">
    <img src="img/watch-story-button.png">
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: .watch-story {
 height: 550px;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(9, 5, 47, .85) 0%, rgba(49, 29, 94, .85) 100%), url(../img/watch-story-bg.png);
}

.watch-story-content {
 width: 960px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.watch-story-button img {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.watch-story-button {
 padding-top: 40%;
}

Comment: Ну как я предполагал, что от родительского divа. Но похоже, от чего-то другого считается...

Comment: вся нужная разметка и стили должны быть непосредственно в вопросе, а не комментариях

Comment: @Grundy, ничего в этом вопросе не нужно, всё и так ясно.

Answer (score 1):

> задаю padding-top 40%

В соответствии со спецификацией `padding` и `margin` считаются от ширины, а не от высоты.
Т. о. ты устанавливаешь отступ сверху в 40% ширины страницы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!